# Nintendo DSi SDK : Getting Started

Tags: handheld, nintendo

Does anyone have a good starting point for learning about development for the new Nintendo  DSi? What kind of hardware do you need to develop and test something like this? Can you develop for the DSi using the standard DS? What language do you need to use?

[Bonus Question] : I also heard the new DSi is going to get an App Store similar to Apple - Are developers going to be able to sell games using this?

Comment: To anyone suggesting homebrew kits/cards: Those things break your license agreement so they may NEVER be used!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, the only *legitimate* way to get the Nintendo DS/DSi development kit is to get it straight from Nintendo--requiring you to have a lot of money and preferably a signed contract with a large game publisher.  This is the case with all of the major game consoles, with the possible exception of the Xbox 360 and the XNA framework.  I don't foresee them changing their business model soon; controlling the SDK ensures that the hardware manufacturers will get their cut of the profits for any game that's released for their console.

If you'd like to get an idea of what DS programming is like, there are some "unofficial" (read: hacked and breaking license agreements) homebrew DS programming environments.  Searching Google for "DS Homebrew" will probably turn up a lot of information.

For what it's worth, most development for game consoles, the DS included, is done in C or C++.

Comment: The unofficial DS dev environment is not breaking any license agreements...the compiler is free, it's based on gcc. And the software libraries were written from scratch, using nothing that was copyrighted by Nintendo.

Comment: I don't mean that the tools infringe any copyrights; I'm talking about the license agreement (EULA) that comes with the DS.  If you read it, it says that running unauthorized software or using unauthorized hardware on your DSi voids your warranty and violates the agreement.  See Chapter II here: http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/dsi/en_la/EULA.jsp

Comment: Yet they don't have any right on forcing you how to use your own handheld. Every clause stating that using any "unauthorized" software breaking your warranty might be considered illegal in many countries, making such contract, and clause totally invalid. You OWN the hardware, so you can do with it just what you want, like if you want to burn it on fire :) What you can't do is gain money by doing things like that.

Comment: @StormByte It's not true that you may do anything with your handheld because it is yours. Yes, they have the right to force things on you. That's what license agreements are for. Deal with it or don't buy a handheld.

Comment: @Jop That strongly depends on the country. USA laws are not a good example to think it is that way in the rest of the world. Still (fortunatelly) there are countries in which you can do stuff with the things you buy, with limitations such as not gaining money with it, for example. That applies to hardware. Software of course have different ruling in which for example, it is illegal to try to crack it, but that, does not apply to hardware. You can legally, disasemble, break it, or do whatever you want.

Comment: @StormByte That something isn't illegal doesn't mean it is allowed.

Comment: Nope, since you are paying for *hardware*, therefore, hardware IS yours. Specially, that none of your private usage can legally void your warranty (unless you open it and touch the components). Another example: Rooting your android breaks your warranty? NO Regardless what vendor say. Vendors are not god, and they can ask for whatever they want, but the fact they do not allow an action, does not mean it is not allowed, specially when that clause is not legal (in that case, that clause is effectless)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get started now. Grab a DS 'homebrew' cart; M3, Acekard, Cyclowiz, R4 etc

Checking now, Acekard (http://www.acekard.com/) already have a DSi compatible card. I am sure there are others already.
Technically there is no change between DS and DSi for the Slot 1 cartridges (fully compatable), all the extra features are related to the camera, connectivity and ability to run from the SD card.

For more info on the Dev part, check out the forums of; http://desmume.org
They also have (as the name suggests) a DS emulator for download.

Bonus: Based on past record, the chance Nintendo will open up the NDi for dev is slim to none.
 I think there was talk about it on the Wii via WiiWare, but there has been nothing new on that area for a long time. Just releases from known/established companies.

Comment: Too update my post a little. Nintendo did end up opening an 'app store' for the DSi. Alas, as with the Wii one getting stuff on there is not so easy.

Answer (score 3):

I tried developing on the DS a while back. From what I remember, DevKitPro had an ARM library you could use. I worked mostly with Func-C, but C++ is supported. Technically, I think you can program on anything that has a compiler for the ARM architecture.

I'm looking to get into it again when the DSi is launched in Canada. The faster processor, persistent storage and more memory should produce some sweet home-brew.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do a little DS development for fun, the devkitPro homebrew kit is reasonably sophisticated at this point.  Here is a link to a manual which gives an introduction to coding a simple game with this kit:
http://www.patater.com/manual

Sadly, if you want to get the official toolkit even to become a DSIware developer it looks like you have to have an established game company and cough up a few thousand bucks.
http://www.nintendolife.com/forums/dsiware/info_on_dsi_ware_development